# How do we claim that the cardinality of $(0,1)$ is $c$?

Tags: real-analysis

The smallest transfinite number is $\aleph_0$ which is of $\mathbb{N}$.

Then we know that the cardinality of $P(\mathbb{N})$ is $2^{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak{c}$ (the cardinality of the continuum) and that $\mathfrak{c}$ is the cardinality of the smallest uncountable set (by continuum hypothesis).

We know that $(0,1)$ is uncountable but why does it have the cardinality as $\mathfrak{c}$?

Comment: There are many was to prove it, the easiest is to use CSB, by getting an injection in between $\mathbb{R}$ and $(0,1)$ by coding the reals as binary sequences.(Since $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})  \approx 2^\mathbb{N}$)

Comment: Is there a way to show that $P(N)$ and $R$ have the same cardinality?

Comment: Of course, $\Card(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\ge\Card(\mathbb{R})$ (think dedekind cuts) and the reverse direction follows by my comment above.

Comment: $\tanh^{-1}(2x-1)$ gives a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @legionwhale ... I agree this is part of the answer.  But the OP seems to define $\mathfrak c$ as the cardinal of $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$.

Comment: @GEdgar As it was referred to as the cardinality of the continuum, I assumed the author knew that it was the cardinality of the real numbers. I didn't read the previous comments.

Answer (score 0):

One way that you can go about it is this.

First, consider the function $f:\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)\to\Bbb R$ given by $$f(A):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\chi_A(n)}{2^n},$$ where $\chi_A:\Bbb N\to\{0,1\}$ is the indicator function of $A,$ given by $$\chi_A(n):=\begin{cases}1 & n\in A\\0 & n\notin A.\end{cases}$$ Show that

- $f$ is an injective function,
- $f(A)\in[0,1]$ for all $A\in\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N),$ and that
- for all $y\in[0,1],$ there is some $A\in\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)$ such that
  $f(A)=y$.

To prove the last part, consider the infinite binary expansions of the elements of $[0,1].$ From this, we can conclude that the cardinal of $[0,1]$ is $\mathfrak{c}.$

Finally, find injective functions $g:[0,1]\to(0,1)$ and $h:(0,1)\to[0,1].$ By [Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem), we conclude that the cardinal of $(0,1)=\mathfrak{c}.$

Note that this does not require the continuum hypothesis to be true in order to hold.